How to post xml data to server using javascript and PHP
Trying to use POST method to send xml data.  The javascript is as follows
     let httpreq = new XMLHttpRequest();

     httpreq.open('POST',url,false);

     httpreq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

     httpreq.send("'xml'" + '=' + encodeURIComponent(xmlString));

The following PHP code gets executed and indicates no data was sent or
not stored in the $_POST variable
 fwrite($fp,'string size ' . sizeof($_POST) . PHP_EOL);    {get  0  written to $fp}

 $xmlString = $_POST['xml'];                               { get undefined index }

The XML data (shown below) does get sent and processed correctly when using GET method,
unfortunately when I try to send larger amounts of XML the GET method gets rejected.
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> <model><modelName>azsxdc</modelName> <cadSpline> <cadType>'cadSpline'</cadType> <id>'spline0'</id> <cls>'spline'</cls><stroke>'black'</stroke><strokeWidth>'3'</strokeWidth><cadPoint><xval>'59.641'</xval><yval>'440'</yval><zval>'0'</zval><id>'splPoint0'</id></cadPoint><cadPoint><xval>'157.641'</xval><yval>'475'</yval><zval>'0'</zval><id>'splPoint1'</id> </cadPoint> <cadPoint> <xval>'233.641'</xval> <yval>'467'</yval> <zval>'0'</zval> <id>'splPoint2' </id> </cadPoint> </cadSpline> </model>

I tried different content_type  for setRequestHeader
but got the same unsucessful results.  I am running
apache webserver.  The apache error log only shows
me the  Undefined index: xml  - which makes sense
since $_POST seems to be empty.

First it's 2024, you should consider using fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest to send data.
Then you need to consider how to receive the data on the server side.

If you try to receive it through $_POST['xml'], you should encode the sent data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Javascript:
async function sendXml(url, xmlString) {
    const xmlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(xmlString);

    const resp = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body: `xml=${xmlEncoded}`
    });

    //print the response text
    console.log(await resp.text());
}

PHP
$xml = $_POST['xml'];


If you try to receive it through the whole request body, you can encode the sent data as application/xml, and read the text through php://input stream.
Javascript:
 headers: {
     "Content-Type": "application/xml"
 },
 body: xmlString

PHP:
 $xml = file_get_contents("php://input");



